# Fill Remaing Space With REPEATING BG Div (CSS)

Tags: html, css, width

I have three boxes contained inside of three div tags referencing IDs like the one below (roughly). I want the third box to just fill the remaining space. My issue is that it is a repeating background. Any suggestions?

```
#box3{
    background-image: url("box3.png");
    background-size: 80px 80px;
    bottom: 35px;
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 1120px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px; }
```

I also would like to note I have tried `overflow: hidden;`, `width: auto;`, `width: 100%;`, `flex-grow: 1;`, and a few others I forget.

My appreciation and gratitude in advance to all those who answer!

Comment: Could you show the problem with Snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#box3 {
      background-image: url("box3.jpg");
      background-size: 80px 80px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      bottom: 35px;
      float: left;
      height: 160px;
      margin: 50px 0 0 1120px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 800px; 
    }
```

Comment: Foremost much appreciation for the quick answer. Unfortunately the repeating background is actually desired. :-(